# Let $u\in W^{1,p}(0,1)$ with $1<p<\infty$ and $u(0)=0$, then $u(x)/x\in L_x^p(0,1)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\in W^{1,p}(0,1)$ with $1<p<infty$ and $u(0)=0$, that is, $u$ has weak derivative $u'$ and $u,u'\in L^p$, then I wish to show that $\tfrac{u(x)}{x}\in L_x^p(0,1)$. Moreover, I wish to prove the inequality $$\left\lVert\frac{u(x)}{x}\right\rVert_{L_x^p(0,1)}\le\frac{p}{p-1}\lVert u'\rVert_{L^p(0,1)}$$

I have succeeded in showing that there must be some sequence $\varphi_n\in C_0^\infty(0,1]$ such that $\varphi_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}u$ in $W^{1,p}(0,1)$, so it is clear that $\varphi_n(x)/x\in L_x^p(0,1)$, but I'm at an impasse, since I don't know how to show even that $$\left\lVert\frac{\varphi_n(x)}{x}\right\rVert_{L^p}$$ is even bounded for all $n$. Am I going in the right direction with this problem?

Comment: Hint: $|\phi_n(x)|=|\phi_n(x)-\phi_n(0)|\leq \int_0^x |\phi_n'(y)|dy.$ Continue from here.

Comment: So I know that $$\left\lvert\frac{\varphi_n(x)}{x}\right\rvert\le\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\left\lvert\varphi_n'(y)\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}y$$ but what do I do with this? Do we know that the $\varphi_n'$ are universally bounded?

Comment: You don't know they are universally bounded, but they are bounded in the $L^p$ norm. Apply Holder's inequality.